# Laravel 5 - get query builder results grouped by column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

For example, I have query:

```php
$posts = DB::table('posts')->select(['id', 'user_id', 'title'])->get();
```

Then `$posts` array looks like this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass) (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(1000)
    ["title"]=>
    string(8) "Post # 1"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass) (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(2000)
    ["title"]=>
    string(8) "Post # 2"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass) (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(2000)
    ["title"]=>
    string(8) "Post # 3"
  }
}
```

As you can see user with `id 1000` have 1 post, user with `id 2000` have 2 posts.

I'd like to get results as associative array with `user_id` as keys:

```
array(2) {
  [1000]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass) (3) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["user_id"]=>
      int(1000)
      ["title"]=>
      string(8) "Post # 1"
    }
  }
  [2000]=>
  array(2) {
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass) (3) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(2)
      ["user_id"]=>
      int(2000)
      ["title"]=>
      string(8) "Post # 2"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass) (3) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(3)
      ["user_id"]=>
      int(2000)
      ["title"]=>
      string(8) "Post # 3"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any nice Laravel solution to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into [Eloquent Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships) instead of using the Query Builder. In your case you have a **one-to-many** relationship. So you'd have a `User` model that looks something like this:

```
class User extends Model {

    public function posts()
    {
        // One User can have many Posts
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }

}
```

And a `Post` model:

```
class Post extends Model {

    public function user()
    {
        // A Post belongs to one User
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}
```

Then you can just get posts by user like this:

```
$users = User::all();

foreach ($users as $user)
{
    $posts = $user->posts;

    // $posts will now contain a Collection of Post models
}
```

Comment: I definitely should refactor existed model to Eloquent, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has no method to do this. But you can do this manually by using this function:

```
public static function makeAssocArrByField($arr, $field)
{
    $assocArr = array();
    foreach($arr as $arrObj)
    {
        if(isset($arrObj[$field]))
            $assocArr[$arrObj[$field]] = $arrObj;
    }

    return $assocArr;
}
```

call method as:

```
$posts = makeAssocArrByField($posts, 'user_id');
```

This will return array as per your required format.